# Why was my Facebook game rejected with the note that "your app icon must not overlap with content in your cover image?"

Tags: facebook

My FB game just recently got rejected for two reasons. The first I fixed, but I just can't see to figure out what they mean by the second, and I was hoping someone else got the same issue and did know what they meant.

The remaining error is:

> **Cover Image**
>
> Your app icon must not overlap with content in your cover image.  Click on 'Web Preview' in the 'App Details' section to check for overlap prior to submitting your app.  See more here.

All I know is that the rejection has something to do with the cover image, not the icons or the screenshots.

The web preview of my game looks like this now:

[image: FB error 2]

Please let me know what to do to get approved.

Comment: The words seems to describe the issue clearly. The content in your cover image (the cloud) is overlapped by the bunny icon.

Comment: Thanks guys, It may seem clear but my english wasnt good enough I think to fully understand what they meant.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: probably because Facebook was pretty clear about what you needed to do (for a change ;)

Comment: I would not have asked if it was clear to me. I tried to google it before asking. It wasn't clear to me especially because Facebook forces icons to overlap with their cover images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Your app icon must not overlap with content in your cover image.**

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Facebook forces the icon and cover image to overlap. Anyways the error is "Your app icon must not overlap with ***content*** in your cover image".